# scanf not behaving properly

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I am trying to input 2 numbers via scanf but scanf throws segmentation fault.

```
void add_prog_1(char *host){
CLIENT *clnt;
int *result_1;
intpair add_1_arg;
int x;
int y;
clnt = clnt_create (host, ADD_PROG, ADD_VERS, "udp");
if (clnt == NULL) {
    clnt_pcreateerror (host);
    exit (1);
} else {

    printf("Connection Established Successfully");
    scanf("%d %d",&x ,&y);
    printf("Input Successfully");
    add_1_arg.a = x;
    add_1_arg.a = y;

}
```

Output of the program is

```
Connection Established Successfully
4 4 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Please help!!

Comment: Your scanf call looks fine. Are you sure it's the `scanf()` call that gives the segfault and not some other part of the code?

Comment: Please use a debugger for this kind of problems. We can't help you here, without an minimal complete example.

Comment: @BlueMoon I guess so output of above code is 
    `Connection Established Successfully
4 4 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)` 4 4 is the input given

Comment: Take a look [here](https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/417/notes/rpc/step5.html).

Comment: @Michi the given program used command line argument not input from console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely somewhere else.
I suspect the output from the second `printf` does not get flushed to the terminal and the program keeps going until you crash somewhere later in the calling function.

Modify the function this way and retest:

```
printf("Connection Established Successfully\n");
scanf("%d %d",&x ,&y);
printf("Input Successfully\n");
fflush(stdout);
add_1_arg.a = x;
add_1_arg.a = y;
```

You should learn to use a debugger such as `gdb`: when the program hits a segmentation fault, the OS dumps a file named `core` that you can load with the debugger.  It contains all the info to point exactly when the fault occurred.